# The inverse of a bijective holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U,V$ are open sets in $\mathbf{C}$, if $f:U\to V$ is holomorphic and bijective, then  the inverse of $f$ $f^{-1}:V\to U$ is also holomorphic.
 How can I show that $f^{\prime}(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in U$ using the cauchy integral formula or its consequences?
Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Is it given that $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic, or is that what you ultimately want to prove, by showing that $f'(z) \neq 0$ for all $z\in U$?

Comment: I want to prove that $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic by showing that $f^{-1}(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in U$. But I want to prove $f^{-1}(z)\neq 0$ using the cauchy formula. I've already done it with loal form. Can it be made with cauchy integral formula?

Comment: Aside: We can show that $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic with the residue theorem, without first showing that $f'$ has no zeros. That is quite nice, and also a generalisation of that is often useful. Using the integral formula or another variant/consequence of the residue theorem to directly show that $f'$ has no zeros, I have no immediate idea. Let me think a little.

Answer (score 1):

It is given that $f$ is holomorphic.  $df$, the Jacobian of $f$, is the matrix

$u_x$  $v_x$

$u_y$  $v_y$

Since $f$ is injective, it must be locally injective too, and so the determinant of the matrix above is nonzero.

But using the Cauchy Riemann equations, you will see (steps not shown here) that the determinant of the matrix above being nonzero for all $z$ is the same thing as

$|f'(z)| \neq 0$

for all $z$, which implies

$f'(z) \neq 0$

for all $z$.

Answer (score 0):

Use Inverse Function Theorem to obtain $f^\prime(z)\neq0$ for all $z$.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, the fact that $f'(z)\neq 0$ is the hypothesis of the inverse function theorem. That is exactly the part I need to prove. I did it with local form already, but want to do it with Cauchy formula.